# Test deeply nested MaterialUI components with enzyme/jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to test a component with the following structure. The nested components are all from Material-UI.

Component.js

```
handleClickA = () => {
   this.setState({propA: null});
}

handleClickB = () => {
   this.handleClickA();
   if (this.state.mounted) {
     this.logoutUser();
   }
}

<div>
  <Poppers>
    <Grow>
      <Paper>
        <ClickAwayListener>
          <MenuList>
            <MenuItem
              onClick="this.handleClickA"
              test-id="menu-item-A"
            >
            {textA}
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              onClick="this.handleClickB"
              test-id="menu-item-B"
            >
            {textB}
            </MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </Paper>
    </Grow>
  </Poppers>
</div>
```

I have been trying to access the  components using both mount and shallow and then access them using enzyme's .find(), .dive(), all sorts of things. I want to simulate a click on the  and then check the state of the wrapper to see if the props have been changed.

Component.test.js

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component />) 
OR 
const wrapper = mount(<Component />)

e.g.
expect(wrapper.find("[test-id='menu-item-A']").length).toBe(1);
wrapper.setState({propA: 'value'});
wrapper.find("[test-id='menu-item-A']").simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.state('propA')).toEqual(null)
```

I feel like I've tried everything to access these components, why can I not 'find' them and simulate the click? I would really appreciate some help, I'm very new to this. It is not in my power to change anything significant about the code structure or to use non-Material-UI. I have to work with what I have...

Comment: Material-UI provides you with a `createMount` function which wraps enzymes `mount`. That should solve your issue, as MenuItems, will be rendered using React Portals which enzyme is currently unable to handle correctly. You maybe want to take a look at: https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with the createMount and co. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem, I still cannot '.find()' the deeply nested components, but it has given me a new kick-off point for researching.

Comment: Even createMount does not working